# Azure LogicApp Stored Procedure step cannot see Azure Managed Instance when setting the connection

Tags: azure

My requirement is the read a rowset returned by a stored procedure which is on Azure Managed instance through a Azure Logic App step. In the Logic App i am using a 'SQL Stored Procedure (V2)' step. When I reference the Managed Instance the connector cannot resolve (see) the instance and I am unable to connect.

Comment: I solved my issue by taking a different approach. I answered my own question in SuperUser, the answer does however not resolve this issue. https://superuser.com/questions/1498143/how-do-i-pass-dataset-or-result-of-stored-procedure-managed-instance-to-a-web/1498607#1498607